# PHP File Upload not updaing database or uploading file

Tags: php, file-upload

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out this issue, what I am trying to do is

- Check to see if the image textbox is blank or not
- See if the file is a jpg or pjpeg, if not return invalid image
- see if there are any errors
- If an error, display error if not upload the file then update database...

Here is my case:

```
case"updatesubmit":
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        if (($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")){
            if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0){
                echo $_FILES["image"]["error"];
            }else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
                "../upload/CV_1_" . date("Ymd") . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);    
                $class->update($id, $text, $image);
                echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Updated!</strong></div>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Invalid Image!</strong></div>";
        }
    }else{
        $class->updateWithoutImage($id, $text);
        echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Updated!</strong></div>";
    }
        $array = $class->view();
        include("view/CV/view_display.html");
    break;
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be awesome!!!

Comment: what is your problem? you detail only what you want to do, not the error

Comment: When I goto upload a file I get Invalid Image! returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could edit your code in this way:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
if($type!=2){ // SO IS NOT JPG
//ERROR
}
```